# How to add application icon in remote view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to show the custom notification in android, i am receiving the notification, the missing part, i need to show the application icon on the left side of the notification is this possible.

Custom_notification.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        style="Custom Notification Title" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
        style="Custom Notification Text" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
        style="Custom Notification Text2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `android:drawableLeft` property in your layout.

> **android:drawableLeft**
>
> The drawable to be drawn to the left of the text.
>
> May be a reference to another resource, in the form
>   "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form
>   "?[package:][type:]name".
>
> May be a color value, in the form of "#rgb", "#argb", "#rrggbb", or
>   "#aarrggbb".
>
> This corresponds to the global attribute resource symbol drawableLeft.

The android docs on [drawableLeft](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3AdrawableLeft).

Comment: Problem with my logo. i used ic_launcher.png its seats fine.